# Function as a parameter javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, function-parameter

I have a function like this :

```
module.exports.download = function (cb) {
   // Some Code
   cb(); 
}
```

Is it the same to do this :

```
module.exports.copyimagefromalbumnext  = function (callback) {
    module.exports.download(callback);
}
```

or

```
module.exports.copyimagefromalbumnext  = function (callback) {
    module.exports.download( function () { callback(); } );
}
```

In advance thanks.

Comment: Well, the latter one is a syntax error as you could easily test yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the error in my code. Please check again. Maybe there a re no difference.

Comment: Yes, please check again. There's still a sxntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `callback` the same as `function () { callback(); }`

No. The second function neither cares about [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), passed arguments, nor the return value of an invocation. You could do

```
function() { return callback.apply(this, arguments); }
```

but that's just superfluous. Use the first approach and pass `callback` itself.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for youe help. I'm new in nodejs. Can you give me some link for better understand how context is managed. I don't understand wich context is associate to the callback function.

Comment: One more precision please. Does callback.apply(this, arguments); attach the callback function to the current object this ? In the first manner ( just callback) the  contect is the document where callback was define ? I'm right ?

Comment: No, the context is always just what the caller decides it to be.